# How to convert an image to 1bit/px binary bitmap with ImageMagick or RMagick?

Tags: image-processing, bitmap, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm looking for the command and options to convert images (png, jpeg, whatever…) to 1bit/px bitmap image (similar to what happen when in photoshop when you convert it to bitmap). See example below

I'd like to do it programatically from within a rails app (e.g. RMagick or through ImageMagick)

[image]

The following works :

```
convert yo.jpg -remap pattern:gray30 mono.gif
```

but I' like to understand better what's happening, compared to what phosotsohp would do in that case; considering the many possibilities explained [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/)  (@roger_rowland thx for the link again)

In the end what I want to do is to have this "effect", and to enlarge the image without ending up with a blurry effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you just need to look at the [ImageMagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/) covering quantization and dithering, which I think is exactly what you're asking. Is it?

Ok - to make sure you don't get blurring when resizing, you will need to retain a copy of the original image (i.e. before half-toning or dithering or whatever). Then when you need to resize, do the resize (up or down, with suitable interpolator) on a copy of the original image, then repeat the monochrome conversion on this resized copy of the original to get your resized monochrome.

**EDIT** - following your latest comment, try something like this:

```
convert yo.jpg -colorspace Gray -ordered-dither h4x4a -scale 2000x2000 mono.png
```

Comment: Allright, the thing I really look for is to enlarge the image without making it blurry; and (sorry to talk about it) in photoshop the image converted in bitmap does not get blurry when resized, you keep this "pixel effect"

Comment: With this >> convert yo.jpg -remap pattern:gray30 -transparent '#ffffff' -scale 2000x2000 mono.png I pretty much get what I want (I was stuck for a moment with resize instead of scale)

Comment: But still, pattern:gray30 seems to be more of a predefined setup; looking to control a bit more this effect

Answer (score 8):

**`-monochrome`**

This option uses some smart dithering and generates very visible output:

```
convert -monochrome in.png out.png
```

Documentation: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#monochrome

Compare that to a simpler `-threshold 50` transform:

```
convert -threshold 50 in.png out.png
```

which loses most of the image. We could likely have improved that with a better `-threshold` value, but the beauty of `-monochrome` is that it is smarter and often works without us having to guess anything.

Concrete example from: https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/galex/pia15416.html

```
wget -O orig.jpg http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/650137main_pia15416b-43_full.jpg
# Downsize to 400 height to have a reasonable file size for upload here.
convert orig.jpg -resize x400 in.jpg
convert -monochrome in.jpg out.jpg
convert -threshold 50 in.jpg threshold-50.jpg
```

in.jpg

[image]

out.jpg

[image]

threshold-50.jpg

[image]

Related questions:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/9868/convert-an-image-from-grayscale-to-binary
- https://superuser.com/questions/75373/convert-color-photos-of-documents-to-good-black-and-white-bitonal-images
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108613/how-do-you-binarize-a-colored-image

Tested in Ubuntu 19.10, ImageMagick 6.9.10.

Comment: Do note, 8 bit for PNG is not the smallest depth possible for PNG 1 bit is.They can store different 2 types of 1 bit png (color-type 0, and 3).